# Close particular buffer immediately upon leaving it

Tags: autocompletion

I have a really large file with many paths in it. I don't want it to participate in any of the completion mechanisms. Is there a way to mark a particular buffer as "not a candidate for keyword completion" or, equivalently, to close it as soon as I leave the buffer?

Here's some motivation for doing it.

I have a file called `~/FILES` that consists of two columns like this, with the name of a file in the left column and the full path on the right. It's just a manually generated index with a very simple format.

Here's an excerpt of the file showing part of the Linux kernel source.

```
ABCDBCDA.c                              ~/ws/opt/linux/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCDBCDA.c
ABCDBDDA.c                              ~/ws/opt/linux/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCDBDDA.c
ABI.txt                                 ~/ws/opt/linux/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/ABI.txt
ABI.txt                                 ~/ws/opt/linux/Documentation/mn10300/ABI.txt
```

This file is very long and really slows down keyword completion.

I've been using this binding to delete the buffer when following paths using `gf`, the most common way to exit the `~/FILES` buffer.

```
nnoremap <silent> gf gf:silent! bdelete ~/FILES<cr>
```

but it's really modifying the behavior in the wrong place.

Is there a better way of marking the buffer?

Comment: you could set the 'bufhidden' option for that buffer. Not sure it will achieve what you actually want.

Comment: When you say "not a candidate for keyword completion", do you mean that you don't want the words in that file to be included as possible completions when you are editing other files?

Comment: @Rich yes exactly. Semantically the `~/FILES` file is not a file I’m editing, it’s a naive way of emulating an almost-plugin. @ChristianBrabandt I will try that and report back.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking for, you could use autocmd to close ~/FILES when you leave this buffer.

```
autocmd BufLeave,BufWinLeave ~/FILES :bd ~/FILES
```

This way, everytime you "leave" this buffer (using :e or :n etc.) it will close ~/FILES.

Hope this helps.